# Sessions automatically unset,after redirecting on other function in codeigniter3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, session-variables

My Code for first function is this one,i have used 'currentsite' as my session variable and i want this session variable in my cart function.

```
    public function productDetail()
{   
    $data['siteID']=$this->session->userdata('siteID');
    $productID=$this->input->get('product_id');
    $stock=$this->siteCRUD->stockDetails($productID);
    $siteID=$stock[0]->site_id;
    if($this->session->userdata('siteID')=='')
    {

        $this->session->set_userdata('siteID',$siteID);
    }
    $site=$this->siteCRUD->GetSitebyID($siteID);
    $this->session->set_userdata('currentsite',$site);
    $data['products']=$this->siteCRUD->getSiteProducts($siteID);
    // $this->add_count($siteID);
    $product=$this->metaCRUD->getProductByCatagory($site[0]->catagory_id);
    $data['siteID']=$this->input->get('id');
    $data['product']=$product;
    $data['productDetail']=$stock;
    $data['productMeta']=$this->siteCRUD->getProductMeta($product[0]->product_id);
    $data['stockMetaDetail']=$this->siteCRUD->productMetaDetails($productID);
    $site=$this->session->userdata('currentsite');
    $data['site']=$site[0];

    $data['page_name']='product-details';
    $this->load->view($site[0]->theme_link.'/index',$data);

}
```

My other function is this one,when i vardump(this->session->currentsite),i get the session varbale empty in this function.

```
    public function cart()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id')=='')
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    $site=$this->siteCRUD->GetSitebyID($this->session->userdata('siteID'));
    $this->session->set_userdata('currentsite',$site);
    $data['siteID']=$this->session->userdata('siteID');
    $site=$this->session->userdata('currentsite');
    $cartItems=$this->siteCRUD->cartItems();
    $data['items']=$cartItems;

    $data['site']=$site[0];
    $data['page_name']='cart';
    $this->load->view($site[0]->theme_link.'/index',$data);

}
```

Comment: Try to download latest version of CI

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write `$this->session->userdata('currentsite')` instead `this->session->currentsite` when dumping the data.

But, if you have correctly about that. Try to check session time expiration configuration at `application\config\config.php` and find `$config['sess_expiration']`.